# A top-down terminal

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, terminal

Does a top-down terminal exist for Mac OS, similar to [Guake](http://labs.alfaiati.net/guake/), [YaKuake](http://yakuake.uv.ro/), or [Tilda](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tilda/)?

Comment: Have you tried those options with X11?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try [Visor](http://visor.binaryage.com/) (now renamed to [TotalTerminal](http://totalterminal.binaryage.com/))

It provides a nice **"top-down"** terminal like you can find in fps game and also some other enhancements.

[image]

Comment: I love Visor. (2 more to go).

Comment: On any new Mac, Visor is consistently one of the first programs I install. Set a keyboard shortcut to enable showing/hiding the Terminal and you're off to the races. I prefer fading it in rather than sliding down, but that's just me.

Comment: yeah! is great, now called totalTerminal

Comment: The default window has only 24 lines, how to change the default setting?

Comment: Visor is now TotalTerminal - TotalTerminal is now discontinued - any other suggestions?

Comment: Dosen't works properly with El Capitan

Answer (score 6):

[TotalTerminal](http://totalterminal.binaryage.com/) is a plugin for the default Terminal application.

[image: TotalTerminal SShot]

Visor was renamed as TotalTerminal.

---

**Update:** I use [iTerm2](https://www.iterm2.com/) now, which has dropdown terminal option in preferences.

Comment: And is now no longer developed

Comment: Dosen't works properly with El Capitan

Comment: Check here: (https://www.sharmaprakash.com.np/guake-like-dropdown-terminal-in-mac/) to set configuration for drop-down terminal